# [solved] How to publish multiple messages from single topic?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hai,

I have a problem in my code. i have to publish multiple messages from single topic, to display 2 voltages which is data type of Float64.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>


ros::NodeHandle nh;

float voltage1 = 23.44, voltage2 = 74.43;


std_msgs::Float64 test;
ros::Publisher p("my_topic", &test);

void setup()
{

  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(p);

}

void loop()
{
  test.data = voltage1;
  test.data = voltage2;
  p.publish( &test );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

when i did this, i only getting

> voltage2

value.how can i publish both?

```
melvin@melvin-HP-Notebook:~$ rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [1537962733.845694]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1537962733.851536]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [1537962735.962522]: Requesting topics...
[INFO] [1537962740.982019]: Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [1537962740.983027]: expected msg length is 84
[WARN] [1537962740.984163]: Last read step: data
[WARN] [1537962740.985069]: Run loop error: Serial Port read failure: Returned short (expected 84 bytes, received 83 instead).
[INFO] [1537962740.985887]: Requesting topics...
```

I got this error while connecting through serial_node after add this line `test.layout.dim_length = 2;`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304294/%5Bsolved%5D-how-to-publish-multiple-messages-from-single-topic?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

you must to use Float32MultiArray

```
#include <ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h"


ros::NodeHandle nh;

float voltage1 = 23.44, voltage2 = 74.43;

std_msgs::Float64MultiArray test;

ros::Publisher p("my_topic", &test);

void setup()
{

  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(p);
  test.data = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) *2);
  test.data_length =2;

}

void loop()
{
  test.data[0]= voltage1;
  test.data[1] = voltage2;
  p.publish( &test );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

if you want to publish single float via topic change this part of code:

```
void loop()
{
  test.data = voltage1;
  p.publish( &test );// add this line
  test.data = voltage2;
  p.publish( &test );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-26**:
Hi Hamid, i got this error

```
exit status 1
request for member 'at' in 'test.std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::data', which is of non-class type 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::_data_type* {aka float*}'
```

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
change test.data.at(0)  to test.data[0] and see the err is gone?

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-26**:
No Hamid. same error.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
did you chang both line :

```
test.data.at(0) = voltage1;
test.data.at(1) = voltage2;
```

to:

```
test.data[0] = voltage1;
test.data[1] = voltage2;
```

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-26**:
yes Hamid

```
exit status 1
request for member 'resize' in 'test.std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::data', which is of non-class type 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::_data_type* {aka float*}'
```

same error.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
i update the code in answer It will work   , some syntax different in Arduino and c++

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
first and second err not the same ;)

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-26**:
oh sorry. my bad. The code executed without error and uploaded. but how to get those particular values?when i did `rostopic echo /my_topic`  it returns

```
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: []
```

The voltage not showing.How to subscribe those voltage1 and 2 separately?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
add this line at the end of setup

```
test.layout.dim_length = 2;
```

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-26**:
i updated my question. can you check?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-09-26**:
change

```
test.layout.dim_length = 2;
```

to

```
test.data_length =2;
```

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-09-27**:
Thank you so much  @hamid . its working.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2021-05-31**:
Thanks, this helped me a lot!